# Learning java...why on earth is this image flickering/flashing?

Tags: java, gif, flicker, animated

There seem to be a lot of similar problems, but they implement different code...this is just the base code, so I have a feeling I'm doing something very strange/wrong. This is what my code looks like. The gifs are transparent and animated, if that changes things.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class NewClass extends JFrame {
    private JLabel label;
    private JButton button;
    private JTextField textfield;
    private ImageIcon image;
    private JLabel label1;
    private ImageIcon imaged;
    private JLabel label2;

    public NewClass (){
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        label = new JLabel("Hi, I am a label!");
        add(label);
        image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("sprite15_2_1.gif"));
        label1 = new JLabel(image);
        add(label1);
         imaged = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("sprite2_1_1.gif"));
        label2 = new JLabel(imaged);
        add(label2);
        label1.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        label2.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        textfield = new JTextField(15);
        add (textfield);

        button = new JButton("aight");
        add(button);
    }
    public static void main (String args[]){

    NewClass gui = new NewClass();
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.pack();
    gui.setVisible(true);
    gui.setTitle("Elan Vital");
    }
}
```

Edited to contain full code. It's just a simple program.

The Flashing GIF (sprite15_2_1.gif) :

[image: The Flashing GIF]

sprite_2_1_1.gif shows up perfectly, but the bottom half of sprite15_2_1.gif flickers white. I have no idea what's different I: " . I have double-checked the gif to be sure it's not a problem with the file itself...

Comment: Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I posted the full code. Let me know if there's anything else you need!

Comment: You can link the flashing `gif` too.

Comment: I need 10 rep to post images, but I hosted it and posted a link, so hopefully that works just as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were problems with the gif file indeed.

Use any one of the following image instead of the one you posted. `Double buffering` is not necessary.

The image has been corrected in photoshop. There were some redundant frames which may have been causing the flickering but the surprising fact is the image shows correctly on all image viewers but not in Java. So possibility of a java bug.

[image]

[image]

The first image is a bit faster, the second one is slower by 0.2s. Use any one.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling double buffering:

```
label1.setDoubleBuffered(true);
label2.setDoubleBuffered(true);
```

For more info see the javadoc on [Component.setDoubleBuffered](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setDoubleBuffered%28boolean%29).

Comment: Double buffering does not appear to affect it, but it's useful to know! I double-checked to make sure the image isn't somehow corrupted, and it's not. I switched the two images, and it's the same image that messes up...I'm guessing this has to do with size? It's slightly larger than the other animated gif. Right now I'm testing it in Eclipse, is there some way to compile it and look at it outside the program to see if it's just messing up within Eclipse? I kind of doubt this, but it's worth a try...